# Attempting to create a list of structs

Tags: c#, struct

Using C#.  I'm not getting any compile errors but it doesn't seem to be working as planned.  Is there anything incorrect with how I have this list<> of structs setup below?..

```
public struct StockEntry
{         
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public PeriodType Period { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}

List<StockEntry> _stocks = new List<StockEntry>(); 

protected override void Initialize()
{ 
    //5min price bars
    _stocks.Add(new StockEntry { Name = "ABC", Period = PeriodType.Minute, Value = 5, Count = 0 } );
    _stocks.Add(new StockEntry { Name = "ACE", Period = PeriodType.Minute, Value = 5, Count = 0 } );
    _stocks.Add(new StockEntry { Name = "ACN", Period = PeriodType.Minute, Value = 5, Count = 0 } );
    _stocks.Add(new StockEntry { Name = "ADT", Period = PeriodType.Minute, Value = 5, Count = 0 } );
    _stocks.Add(new StockEntry { Name = "SCTY", Period = PeriodType.Minute, Value = 5, Count = 0 } );

    //1min price bars
    _stocks.Add(new StockEntry { Name = "ABC", Period = PeriodType.Minute, Value = 1, Count = 0 } );
    _stocks.Add(new StockEntry { Name = "ACE", Period = PeriodType.Minute, Value = 1, Count = 0 } );
    _stocks.Add(new StockEntry { Name = "ACN", Period = PeriodType.Minute, Value = 1, Count = 0 } );
    _stocks.Add(new StockEntry { Name = "ADT", Period = PeriodType.Minute, Value = 1, Count = 0 } );
    _stocks.Add(new StockEntry { Name = "SCTY", Period = PeriodType.Minute, Value = 1, Count = 0 } );
}
```

**added portion below****

Anywhere where it has Count are the critical areas where I'm unsure if it's actually counting the # of trades as I'm trying to accomplish.

```
protected override void OnBarUpdate()
{   
    // for loop to iterate each stock through the required 
    // entry conditions. "series" is just a 5min price bar 
    // of each instrument,   "series + 5" is 1min of each 
    // instrument.  Hoping the first stock I added above 
    // takes Index 1, then the next stock added takes Index 2 and so on.                
    for (int series = 0; series < 5; series++)
    {
        if (BarsInProgress == series + 5) //OnBarUpdate called for 1min bars
        {    
            var stockEntry = _stocks[series];
            bool enterTrade = false;

            if (stockEntry.Count < 1)//if 0 entries
            {
                enterTrade = true;
            }
            else // if 1 or more entries make sure 2 price bars or 10min has elapsed before entering another trade
            {
                enterTrade = BarsSinceEntry(series, "", 0) > 2;
            } 

            if (enterTrade)
            {  
                // Condition for Long Entry, fast MA cross above slow MA & current price > high of bar at cross
                if (SMA(BarsArray[series],Fast)[1] > SMA(BarsArray[series],Slow)[1] && 
                    SMA(BarsArray[series],Fast)[2] < SMA(BarsArray[series],Slow)[2] && 
                    Closes[series + 5][0] > Highs[series][1] + distance && 
                    SMA(BarsArray[series],Slow)[1] > SMA(BarsArray[series],Slow)[2] + .01)
                {        
                    EnterLong(200); //enter long 200 shares

                    // store/track that a trade for the current stock has 
                    // taken place so that it can process through the condition 
                    // above that requests how many trades have already taken place.
                    stockEntry.Count++;                     }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what's not working as planned?

Comment: The local variable, obviously.  Gone after the method returns, no more list.

Answer (score 0):

As Hans suggested, try moving the _stocks variable outside the Initialise method. See example below.

```
List<StockEntry> _stocks = new List<StockEntry>(); // Make it a class variable, not a method variable.           

protected override void Initialize()
{                       
    //5min price bars
    _stocks.Add(new StockEntry { Name = "ABC", Period = PeriodType.Minute, Value = 5, Count = 0 } );
    ....
}
```

Comment: I already had it defined as a field of the class using private List<StockEntry> _stocks;

Comment: Any idea why I was blocked from posting further posts?  I thought I had a legitimate question in asking if I had structured a list of structs correctly.  I am new to coding so this is not easy.  But either way I already had it defined in the class even though it was redundant.

Comment: You are not being very clear as to what is not working. Give us more details. What behaviour are you expecting to happen with you code?

Comment: Ok I hope this doesn't scare you away.  I added the rest of the code above to try to give the big picture.  I'm attempting to have it Count the # of trades that have taken place per stock, I tried to comment as much as possible in the added code above.  Basically it's not triggering any trades now that I've added in the Count code and the list of structs.  I don't know if it has to with the added stocks not taking on Indexes 0,1,2 etc.(the for loop calls for these integers to recognize which stock is routing thru) or if it has to do with my miscoding of any place where Count is used.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want each variable or list item of type `StockEntry` to hold a combination of name, period, value, and count?  Or do you want each such variable or list item to hold a reference to an entity which has a name, period, value, and count?  Structure types have the former meaning; class types have the latter meaning.

If one has a list of structures and one wishes to modify part of a list item, one must read out the list item, make the change, and *write it back*.  If the list contains a references to a mutable class type, one may read a reference from the list and then modify the object to which it refers without having to update the list.  That is often convenient, but such convenience comes at a cost: if the purpose of the *list* is to encapsulate the information held in the items, one must ensure that each item within the list holds the only reference anywhere in the universe to the `StockEntry` outside of those times when one is actively using the entry in question.  This generally means that the only safe way to expose information within the list to outside code is to copy that information to some other object.

I would suggest that a nice pattern is to define a class something like:

```
class SimpleHolder<T>
{
  public T Value;
  SimpleHolder() {}
  SimpleHolder(T val) {Value = val;}
}
```

and then use a `List<SimpleHolder<StockItem>>`.  If you then define `SimpleHolder<StockItem> stockEntry;`, you will be able to say `stockEntry.Value.Count++;` and have it update the entity held in the list, but will also be able to have methods return a `StockItem` as a means of returning the data contained therein without having to expose the entity that holds it.

Comment: Didn't see response. Maybe I'm setting up the whole thing incorrect.  The only thing that should be changing is the Count(# of times a stock has initiated a new trade).  The other 3 variables are constants..the name is just the name of the stock and the period type is always minute and the value is always 5(5min).  The software I'm using requires the name, period type, and  value for each stock name that is added to the script.  So normally it's just Add("Name", PeriodType.Min, 5) for each stock added.  I'm just bringing in the additional factor of Counting each Stocks # of trades initiated.

Comment: @zirjeo: It sounds as though the "Count" really doesn't belong with the other parts of the `StockEntry`.  You could either define a `CountedThing<T>` class which contains a `Value` of type `T` and a `Count`, and then have a `List<CountedThing<T>>`, or design a type `CountedThingList<T>` which contains a `T[]` or `List<T>`, along with an `int[]` or `List<int>`, and keeps the two arrays or lists "in sync" with each other.  I like to use arrays myself [a `List<T>` is really nothing more than an array and an "active-items" count].

Comment: Add("Stock 1", PeriodType.Min, 5)//becomes Index 1

Comment: It timed out on me.   Add("Stock 1", PeriodType.Min, 5)//becomes Index 1, Add("Stock 2", PeriodType.Min, 5)//becomes Index 2.  Then say 1(Index 1) is run through EnterLong() via the for loop, the count is now one.  So the T[] is just the Indexes 1,2,3.. and the Count is obviously just the # of times Index 1 or 2 or 3 etc. have passed through EnterLong().  So both are of type int, does this sound correct?  So I'm basically just counting the # of times Add("Stock 1", PeriodType.Min, 5) has passed through EnterLong() for instance.

Comment: i was trying to replicate your coding above..can you tell what I'm missing here..public class StockEntry
{
  public string Name;
  public PeriodType Period;
  public int Min;
  
public StockEntry() {}
public StockEntry(string Name, PeriodType Period, int Min) {Value = val;}}  List<StockEntry<StockItem>> _stocks = new List<StockEntry<StockItem>>();

 protected override void Initialize()  _stocks.Add(new StockEntry("ABC", PeriodType.Minute, 5)); {Value = 0;}   
_stocks.Add(new StockEntry("ACE", PeriodType.Minute, 5)); {Value = 0;} }

Comment: @zirjeo: My last suggestion was that you have a `StockEntry` structure which contains everything *but* the count, define a generic class `CountedThing<T>` which contains a public `T Value` and `int Count`, and then have a `List<CountedThing<StockEntry>>`; I'm not sure whether I really like that or would prefer to have `Count` in the `StockEntry` structure and use `a List<SimpleHolder<StockEntry>>`.  I don't really like `StockEntry` as a mutable class, since exchanging data with outside code would require manually copying all the fields.